# JS photogallery. Getting the big image to display and and thumbnails to be clickable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a quick issue that I need help with and hoping a fresh set of eyes can pinpoint my issue. I have a photo gallery and I want to display a larger image of the thumbnail when it is clicked. The thumbnails images show up fine at the bottom but are not clickable and the main (or larger image) does not show up. I am using an external .js file. I will upload the HTML also, and maybe some one can point me in the right direction and help me understand what I am overlooking.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>


<head>
    <title>Photo Gallery Final Project</title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "gallery.css">


</head>

<body>

    <div class = "main">

        <div class = "wrapper">

            <div id = "largeImage">

        <img src = "images/machine_1_big.jpg" alt = "machining image" width = "920" height = "400" id = "myImage" class = "border"/>

            </div>

            <div class = "thumbnail">

              <img src="machine_1.jpg" alt = "machining lathe"   id="machine_1"/>
              <img src="machine_2.jpg" alt = "machining lathe" id="machine_2"/>
              <img src="machine_3.jpg" alt = "machining lathe"  id="machine_3"/>
              <img src="machine_4.jpg" alt = "machining lathe"  id="machine_4"/>
              <img src="machine_5.jpg" alt = "machining lathe"  id="machine_5"/>
              <img src="machine_6.jpg" alt = "machining lathe"  id="machine_6"/>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src = "gallery.js"></script>


</body>




</html>

//this will load the gallery in the browser and enable the gallery function
//window.onload = gallery;
//gallery funtion declared
function gallery(){
     //variable allGalleryImages created. This is where all the images will be held
     var allGalleryImages = document.images;
     //for loop declared for the image array
     for(var i = 0; i < allGalleryImages.length; i++){
          if(allGalleryImages[i].id.indexOf("small") > -1){
              //this will add a listener to the thumb images
               allGalleryImages[i].onclick = imgChanger;

          }
     }
}
//this is the image changer function
function imgChanger(){
     //this will change the src attribute value of the large image.
     //document.getElementById('myImage').src ="images/"+this.id+"_big.jpg";
      document.getElementById('myImage').src =  " " + this.id +"_big.jpg";

}
```

Comment: Are you okay with JQuery?

Comment: Sure. Go ahead and shoot.

Answer (score 0):

I used JQuery. Did not have to change your HTML. And there is no reason to make and array of all the thumbnails.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".thumbnail img").on("click", function() {
        imgChanger($(this).attr("src"));
    })


    //this is the image changer function
    function imgChanger(theSRC) {
        //this will change the src attribute value of the large image.
        //document.getElementById('myImage').src ="images/"+this.id+"_big.jpg";
        var beforeJPG = theSRC;
        console.log(beforeJPG);
        beforeJPG = beforeJPG.substring(0, beforeJPG.length-4);
        console.log(beforeJPG + "_big.jpg");
        $("myImage").attr("src", beforeJPG + "_big.jpg");
    }
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6v8arhp2/

1. Get the `src` of the clicked image
2. Chop off ".jpg"
3. Add "images/" to the front, add "_big.jpg" to the back
4. Change src of `#myImage`

** Of course your images are not inside JSFiddle so you cannot see it work, but the console logs show the transformation.